# (Android Studio java) How to fix error: Failed to find provider for user 0; expected to find a valid ContentProvider for this authority

Tags: java

Dear Stackoverflow Members,

I am working with Camera Intent (default application). When I run to line:

> `getContentResolver().notifyChange(selectedImage, null);`

It throw Exception:

> Failed to find provider for user 0; expected to find a valid ContentProvider for this authority

Please help for me this. Thank you!

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.auditor">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>



    </application>

</manifest>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.auditor;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.File;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final int TAKE_PICTURE = 1;
    private Uri imageUri;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        takePhoto();
    }

    public void takePhoto() {
        StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder builder = new StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder();
        StrictMode.setVmPolicy(builder.build());
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        File photo = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "Pic.jpg");
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photo));
        imageUri = Uri.fromFile(photo);

        try {
            startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_PICTURE);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            String ex = e.getMessage();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        switch (requestCode) {
            case TAKE_PICTURE:
                if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    try {
                        Uri selectedImage = imageUri;
                        getContentResolver().notifyChange(selectedImage, null); //error here
                        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImageView);
                        ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
                        Bitmap bitmap;
                        bitmap = android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(cr, selectedImage);
                        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                        Toast.makeText(this, selectedImage.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Toast.makeText(this, "Failed to load", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Log.e("Camera", e.toString());
                    }
                }
        }
    }


}
```

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i15QD.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have ever done that but I used `Android 8 , API Level 26`.

What version of your app are you using? Can you use `Android Platform 8 (API Level 26)`?

I hope it will help you to ignore this exception.